# Add width & height attributes to Gutenberg’s image output?

Tags: images, block-editor

Images inserted via Gutenberg don't have width & height attribute by default. I'd like to use those for lazy-loading purposes so image is positioned correctly.

Is there a hook or something to add width and height to output? Or should one extend the core block for this?

Comment: isn't there a lazyload JS plugin doens't need width or height attributes? or isn't this an option?

Comment: @AndréKelling not sure about the other plugins, I'm building my own solution. Also before Gutenberg editor width and height were present on every image by default

Answer (score 0):

If affordable i would rather switch to a lazyload technique without the need of width and height attributes on images over somehow hacking of the editors image output.

This saves you maintenance problems that may occur in the future with Gutenberg Editor.

i do made good experiences with this plugin https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/

**edit:**

i'm wrong with my assumption. you would need to edit the image output for another plugin anyway. like for my suggested one with `data-src` to an image.

Comment: Seems like lazyload plugin from your link also uses width & height: `<img class="lazyload" data-src="img/example.jpg" width="765" height="574">
<img class="lazyload" src="img/example-thumb.jpg" data-src="img/example.jpg" width="765" height="574">`

Comment: hmm.. but shouldn't be necessary and work without these attributes. But of course `data-src` is needed and also not part of your default gutenberg output... i'm wrong here.